# Fiddler shows strange POST request

Tags: fiddler

When I have [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) up and running, it shows me a strange POST request being sent to my localhost from Amazon.com every few seconds.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

I feel like all these 502 Errors could be slowing down my machine.

```
POST http://localhost:4751/morpho HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4751
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Origin: https://www.amazon.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sk;q=0.6
```

The response my localhost sends back is:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 18:56:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 14:56:12.924

[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. <br />Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). <br />System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4751
```

**Edit:** I realize now that this was because I had the Amazon Music player open.  However, it is still not clear why it was trying to POST to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Amazon Cloud player running in the background. Close all instances of Amazon Cloud Player and you'll be fine.

Comment: Good guess - that was it.